# ChildFragmentManager.getFragment() and NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a parent fragment hosting a child fragment. 
I stress-test my app, forcing it to be killed by checking "Don't keep activities" in Developer Options, then pressing Home button.

I can see that `onSaveInstanceState` of the parent fragment is called, the code of the function is:

```
if (mDetailFragment!=null){
    getChildFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,FRAGMENT_ROUTE,mDetailFragment);
}
```

Then when I restore the app, seeing that `onCreate` of the parent fragment is called with NON-null and NON-empty savedInstanceState, I can see the bundle containing the index FRAGMENT_ROUTE. However, when I call `getFragment`, it always crashes. Code is below:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    mDetailFragment = new RouteFragment();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.v4_fragment_route, mDetailFragment).commit();
} else {
    //first try to find the fragment in a normal way
    mDetailFragment = (RouteFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.v4_fragment_route);
    //if cannot, then use getFragment
    if (mDetailFragment== null){
        mDetailFragment = (RouteFragment) fragmentManager.getFragment(savedInstanceState,FRAGMENT_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

The crash log is like below, it looks like the index list is empty. What am I missing? Thanks

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:583)
            at com.myapp.android.appname.fragment.HomeFragment.onCreate(HomeFragment.java:170)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1764)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1127)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1109)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1913)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:267)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
            at com.buzzhives.android.tripplanner.ProgressEnabledActivity.onCreate(ProgressEnabledActivity.java:25)
            at com.buzzhives.android.tripplanner.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5934)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1279)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5223)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Have you resolved the issue yet?

Answer (score 4):

The fragment (no fragment) has been created yet.  You can't call getFragment before any fragments exist or it crashes.  It probably shouldn't (should probably return null), but its a bug.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear, just update the code. When onCreate() is called, I check whether it's new or a restored state. Updated code above

Comment: I'm looking at the aosp code. That line is accessing an array list of fragments that are active. It's null because no fragment is active yet. The list gets created when the first fragment becomes active